# custom jQuery serializeArray()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this serialize array function:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
     var o = {};
     var a = this.serializeArray();
     $.each(a, function () {
         if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
             if (!o[this.name].push) {
                 o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
             }
             o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
         } else {
             o[this.name] = this.value || '';
         }
     });
     return o;
 };
```

and normally submitting a form would produce an output like this.

```
{
    "acctType1": "individual",
    "compare_act1": "contains",
    "match_name_act1": "accountName",
    "text_act1": "",
    "acctType2": "individual",
    "compare_act2": "contains",
    "match_name_act2": "accountName",
    "text_act2": "",
    "transType1": "401kContribution",
    "compare_trans1": "contains",
    "match_name_trans1": "description",
    "text_trans1": "",
    "transType2": "401kContribution",
    "compare_trans2": "contains",
    "match_name_trans2": "description",
    "text_trans2": ""
}
```

I would like to return it something like:

```
custom = {
    acct: {
        "acctType1": "individual",
        "compare_act1": "contains",
        "match_name_act1": "accountName",
        "text_act1": "",
        "acctType2": "individual",
        "compare_act2": "contains",
        "match_name_act2": "accountName",
        "text_act2": ""
    },
    trans: {
        "transType1": "401kContribution",
        "compare_trans1": "contains",
        "match_name_trans1": "description",
        "text_trans1": "",
        "transType2": "401kContribution",
        "compare_trans2": "contains",
        "match_name_trans2": "description",
        "text_trans2": ""
    }
```

Earlier all the keys from the form were coming as a single JSON string , now I would like them in two JSON (arrays..?? not sure about this pretty much one that contains all of acct and one trans ).

Need to format this JSON string. How do I do that?

Comment: What's the problem with sending the data to the server like normal people do and just figure it out serverside, why send twice as much data ?

Comment: Search for the word `trans` in the `.name`. If you find it, add it to the `trans` object. Otherwise, add it to the `acct` object.

Comment: could you make me a fiddle for that.? @cookiemonster

Comment: @user3412193 - Asking someone to make a fiddle for you is saying **write this for me.** While at Stack Overflow we don't mind giving pointers and helping down specific errors, we aren't here to simply do other people's work for them.  The proposed solution really is simply for anyone with basic Javascript knowledge.